# Video Annotation for Neural Network Training

Tags: video, annotations, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I want to train a neural network to recognize some objects in video based on their shape, color, etc. In order to train my NN, I want to have it run against some training video (MP4s that I filmed) so that I can do some supervised learning. 
Are there any tools out there that I can use to draw on video frame-by-frame so that I can pipe it into a NN?

Pretend that we have the example that I want to have a NN recognize red triangles. I want to go through frame-by-frame and "highlight" the areas that have the red triangles so that the NN can scan the frame, say yes/no there's a red triangle and it's here, and check if it's right.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

mj

Comment: I've been messing around with this further and I found a nice Java library called Xuggler that lets you decode video yourself and display it on the screen. I think that this is a 1st step to writing something myself.

Answer (score 0):

Altering the source image will train the network to recognize your annotations, not necessarily the desired object of recognition.  This is probably not the best approach if you want the network to eventually process un-annotated imagery.

I would create a separate file containing the desired output data that should be extracted from each frame, indexed by timecode or frame number.  If you're just detecting the presence of a certain object, it would be sufficient to simply list all frames that contain the object, or better yet, start and stop frames to delineate when it's visible.  Standard captioning tools should work well for this task.

Not really a programming question, though....  Might be more appropriate on SuperUser.

Comment: Yes, I agree w/ what you are saying. I just need the tool to draw the annotations with my mouse and separately save the data off into a database.